# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm essentially trying to continuously update a graph embedded in a tkinter GUI window and am using the **after** function to call the update function after a specified time (10 ms). I get the above error as the callback is executed, however, and I am quite new to tkinter and Python OOP so I could very well be making a basic error. Here's the code (error happens in def update_plot):

```
class PageThree(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        global f, a
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        readbutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Data Collection", command=self.read_data)
        readbutton.pack()

        stopbutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Stop Data Collection",
                     command=self.stop_data)
        stopbutton.pack()

    def read_data(self):
        t_axis = []
        global starttime
        starttime = time()
        self.update_plot()

    def update_plot(self):
        global func_id
        t_axis.append(time()-starttime)
        output.append(random.random())
        a.cla()
        a.plot(t_axis, output)
        func_id = tk.Tk.after(samplerate, self.update_plot) # this is where it runs into an error

    def stop_data(self):
        global func_id
        tk.Tk.after_cancel(func_id)
```

Full traceback error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./gui2.py", line 202, in read_data
    self.update_plot()
  File "./gui2.py", line 211, in update_plot
    func_id = tk.Tk.after(samplerate, self.update_plot)
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 592, in after
    self.tk.call('after', ms)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I'm pretty stumped on this one and haven't found any questions like it elsewhere. Any pointers?

Comment: Which line is the error being thrown at? EDIT: Just saw your edit

Comment: Please provide the full traceback error.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./gui2.py", line 202, in read_data
    self.update_plot()
  File "./gui2.py", line 211, in update_plot
    func_id = tk.Tk.after(samplerate, self.update_plot)
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 592, in after
    self.tk.call('after', ms)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: In your question not the comments lol.

Comment: change `func_id = tk.Tk.after(samplerate, self.update_plot)` to `self.after(samplerate, self.update_plot)`. `tk.Tk` is not a valid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears to be in your after statement.

`tk.Tk` is not what you think it is.

When using `after()` you often apply it to the `root` window or more often `self` when in a class.

So change:

```
tk.Tk.after(samplerate, self.update_plot)
```

To:

```
self.after(samplerate, self.update_plot)
```